# Why G(P/F) and G(Q/F) abelian implies PQ abelian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, radicals

Suppose L/F is a field extension, then L/P/F with P/F abelian and L/Q/F with Q/F abelian implies PQ=P(Q) abelian.

After trying to pick element from PQ, I still can't find the relation between PQ and the fact that G(P/F) and G(Q/F) are abelian.

Comment: Note that there is an injective homomorphism $\varphi : \text{Gal}(PQ/F) \to \text{Gal}(P/F)\times \text{Gal}(Q/F)$. Now use the first isomorphism theorem.

Comment: Oh yes! This is so trivial..Thanks!